# order of integrtion

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> find the volume of a cylinder $4cos\theta$ which intersect from above by $r^2+z^2=16$ and by $z=0$ from below

So the upper plane is $z=\sqrt{16-r^2}$ and the cylinder has a radius from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and from $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ to $2\pi$

the integral of cylinder coordinates is $\iiint r dr dz d\theta$ in this case $2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-r^2}}\int_{0}^{4cos\theta} r dr dz d\theta$

but it does not seems to work, is the order of integrtion can affect?

Answer (score 1):

Since the upper bound for $z$ depends on $r$, we must integrate with respect to $z$ before we integrate with respect to $r$, so we want:
$$
2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{4\cos\theta} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-r^2}} r \, dz \, dr \, d\theta
$$

Comment: sorry for the qeustion but why is $z$ spends on $r$? is it because that height ($z$) depends if the radius get smaller?